# Display .git directory on VS-CODE?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I would like to see the `.git/` folder on Visual Studio Code editor, but for some reason, it's not showing up on the sidebar where all the project folders are. I don't know if this can help you understand better the problem but this is what I get when I do a `ls -la` on my directory

`drwxr-xr-x    .git`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check your [Visual Studio Code settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings),  for "`files.exclude`"

```
  // Configure glob patterns for excluding files and folders. For example, the files explorer decides which files and folders to show or hide based on this setting.
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.svn": true,
    "**/.hg": true,
    "**/CVS": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true
  },
```

You should be able to exclude `.git`, which by default is an hidden folder.

You can do so at the user-level (for all projects), or at the workspace level (just for this particular project)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/naXaM.png]

Comment: `CTRL+,` to open settings